# Element click not working while using custom "keyword driver framework"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I developed Keyword Driven Framework for one site already and it works well. Now I need to create it for a second site and I am trying to click link and it doesn't work. Did someone face this issue or does someone know why this might work on one site and not the other? I am using selenium webdriver 2.33, poi 3.8 to read from excel and all my data including xpaths are contained in the excel file. My JUnit test passes, but the page to the link that I clicked on does not load. I have added numerous wait statements and still no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Provide any error log or other information.

Comment: Why develop your own keyword BDD framework when there are already many, such as JBehave, that are likely to perform much better?  I am assuming also that you are using the Parameterized annotation from JUnit 4.11?  Does the page not load or is it just that Selenium cannot click the element you defined?

Comment: @djangofan The browser opens and navigates to the given URL and passes it is not picking up the click link method and here is the method that is in the eclipse                                    public static void clickLink(WebDriver driver, String xpath){ 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();  
}                                                                                               And all the URLS and xPaths are contained in an excel.

Comment: @Sankumarsingh When I say that it doesn't work I am saying that it is not clicking the link and this works perfectly fine with the other site. I don't have any failed JUnit test.

Answer (score 1):

In such cases I will suggest something which almost always work for you:

Use Selenium IDE (firfox Addon) and record the same event you want to perform, Now either

1. See the particular element is accepting click or clickLink or something different. You can select the particular command from the list of commands in the table and then Click on Target dropdown to see the various ways to locate that element including xpath .
2. OR convert the code in JUnit/Webdriver format and check either the xpath will be wrong or the element may not accpting the click event using xpath.

Comment: Thanks Sir, I tried to download IDE many times but unfortunately it always disappears for me. But I found another solution I guess selenium gets dreadfully slow when we want it to read values from excel and then perform operations on browser. I added numerous wait statements after each different methods.

Comment: Don't download Selenium IDE.  Instead, install "Selenium Builder" .  You will have much better results with that.

Comment: Madi... Its completely your choice how to get out of it. However, as you are saying, it seems that selenium is taking unexpected time in your case. There must be some mistake anywhere. BTW, download IDE from http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.2.0/selenium-ide-2.2.0.xpi and after installation, check it under tools of your firefox browser.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is handle the exception that is thrown.  You do not say, but I am assuming you are getting a ElementNotFound exception, or similar.  All you need to do is handle it gracefully and by putting the .findElement method in a loop, you can retry for a certain amount of time until it succeeds.   Another way to do it is to use [FluentWait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) with the .ignoring method.

[I wrote multiple ways of doing that here.](https://gist.github.com/djangofan/5112655)

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it. Actually in all honesty there was no exception thrown to me. But I really like your FluentWait code I will try to implement it into my framework.

Comment: Ok, but you only need to do that when it is very clear that the standard "implicit wait" of .findElement  is throwing exceptions.  Otherwise, the standard "implicit wait" is preferred.   The "explicit" method I show above is just a safety route if you need something that is very error resistant.